# Spring Data CrudRepository @Query With LIKE and IgnoreCase

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I need to retrieve some Entity fields from CrudRepository:

```
public class User {
    private String name;

    // getters and setters
}

public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> { 

   @Query("SELECT U.name FROM User U WHERE LOWER(U.name) LIKE LOWER(?1)")
   List<String> findByName(String matchPhrase);
}
```

Basically, I want to get equivalent of SQL query:

```
SELECT u.name FROM user u WHERE LOWER(u.name) LIKE LOWER('match%')
```

The problem is that @Query doesn't works (empty list returned), hibernate generates log:

> Hibernate: select user0_.name as col_0_0_ from user user0_ where lower(user0_.name) like lower(?)

I actually didn't get how to specify a parameter bound with appended %.

```
// also fails at compile-time
@Query("SELECT U.name FROM User U WHERE LOWER(U.name) LIKE LOWER(?1%)")
```

> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: null near line ...

This works fine but returns whole Entity, what may produce long response because I need retrieve only specific fields:

```
List<User> findByNameStartingWithIgnoreCase(String match);
```

Comment: When you ask about an error, always post the exact and complete error message and stack trace. When asking about something that doesn't work, always tell what you expect to happen, and what happens instead.

Comment: If empty list is returned, and you passed `"match%"` as argument to the method, then it simply means that no user has a name starting by 'match'.

Comment: No, I implemented case insensitive service like this, and it works fine, the problem is with second  LOWER() - ... LIKE LOWER(?1)

Comment: What did you pass as argument to the method, and what does the table contain?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this

```
@Query("SELECT U.name FROM User U WHERE LOWER(U.name) LIKE LOWER(concat(?1, '%'))")
List<String> findByName(String matchPhrase);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you need the format `like %name%` (instead of `like name%`) you can expand the accepted answer as follows:

```
@Query("SELECT U.name FROM User U WHERE LOWER(U.name) LIKE LOWER(concat('%', concat(?1, '%')))")
List<String> findByName(String matchPhrase);
```

Answer (score 0):

have you try this syntax:

@Query("SELECT U.name FROM User U WHERE LOWER(U.name) LIKE LOWER(?1)%")
and the just give the name or the beginning of the name

Comment: I've tried but it produces org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: null near line 1, column 104