# Spring data jpa LIKE query not working with space at the end?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Below query i am running in MySQL editor.

```
SELECT * FROM on_plan_test.line_item_meta WHERE name LIKE '%total %';
```

Here i have put one space after word 'total' and this query giving result properly in MySQL workbench, getting three records.

## Below are the data i have in "name" column.

```
    name
    total ftp
    total revenue
    total tax
```

But same query i am running from JAVA

```
@Query(value = "SELECT NEW com.onplan.responsepayload.LineItemForAutoCompleteResponsePayload(sl.lineItemId,s1.sheetId) from LineItemMeta s1 where s1.name like %?1% ")
public List<LineItemForAutoCompleteResponsePayload> getLineItemListForAutoComplete( String name);
```

Above query not giving results. Here in "name"  variable i am passing "total ".  (total word with one space)
What i am doing wrong here?

Comment: Use `Like` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40356896/3094731)

Comment: Please log out the actual statement executed, including the bound parameters. Does it work if you pass in just `"total"` without space, or just `"t"`?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this one

```
 @Query(value = "SELECT NEW com.onplan.responsepayload.LineItemForAutoCompleteResponsePayload(sl.lineItemId,s1.sheetId) from LineItemMeta s1 where s1.name like concat('%',:name, '%')")
public List<LineItemForAutoCompleteResponsePayload> getLineItemListForAutoComplete(@Param("name") String name);
```

Comment: i have implemented your solution but still data not coming.

Comment: Try another solution. It works for me. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately that new solution also not working , surprised how its working for you.